# Unity PNG sequence animation changing position in animation

Tags: unity, animation

We are making frame by frame animation and we have a canvas size for animation. Attack animation is changing position in canvas. In Unity after the attack animation is completed it teleports back to the initial position.
I tried setting animation event and updating parent position but it does not work. It teleports to nonsense locations like player is looking at +x but it teleports to -x. Anybody have solution for this? Since it is not rigged, root motion is not working.

I tried to put animation event at the last frame and put this script to the character controller which is a child object of empty parent object:

```
public void animationFinished(){
 animation_finished = true;
}

 void LateUpdate () {
 if(animation_finished ) {
    
     transform.parent.position = transform.position;
     transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
 }
}
```

I have 25 PNG as frames of animations. From *idle* animation I go to *attack* animation. *Idle* is stable as a position, but *attack* animation is changing position in canvas for example animation canvas is 1920x1080 canvas size and animation starts from the left size to right size. I can't move the character with a script because it has its own timing that I can't set up with script. So I am trying to get the last frame position and pass it to *idle* animation at that position but instead of that without code it teleports back to the initial position after *attack* is completed.

This is a [similar topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172469/unity-2d-animation-from-spritesheet-how-can-i-move-the-character-according-to-t), but the solution did not work.

Comment: We might have a solution, but we need more information. Like how exactly you set up your animations and what behavior exactly you are experiencing.

Comment: It might help if you show us how you've set up your sprites and their pivot points, how you've set up your animation, and how you wrote your repositioning script. Those specifics can help us spot the source of the problem.

Comment: I am using PNG sequence as animation with spaces. and it has canvas size so animator is moving character in the frames. I cant get the last frame position and keep character in the same last position.

Comment: problem is same with this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172469/unity-2d-animation-from-spritesheet-how-can-i-move-the-character-according-to-t   but solution is not working

Comment: I was trying to trigger late update to get parent position to child position but not working

Comment: Do not ping users to ask them to help. Your question already does that. If users had a solution for you, they would share it. Instead, as you can see, we've asked you for more information which you have not provided. Until you provide that information, it's likely we will not be able to answer your question.

Comment: I pinged it becuase I answerd it late and did not know if it is getting notification. I updated the question